# noun phrase or not subsumed into the word snow

Tags: singular-vs-plural, uncountable-nouns

Do you say (1) "There was three feet of snow" or (2) "There were three feet of snow"
when referencing the amount of snow and NOT three-feet made of snow!

I.e. is the phrase "three feet of snow" plural or singular and is it describing the snow or is the snow describing the three feet?

Of course it would help if you could explain why this is so, and of course a source reference.

Comment: According to [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=There+was+three+feet+of%2CThere+were+three+feet+of%2CThere+was+three+foot+of%2CThere+were+three+foot+of&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=10), there's not much to choose between singular/plural *there **was / were** three feet of snow*. But my preferred version ([*There **was** three **foot** of snow*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22There+was+three+foot+of%22)) apparently doesn't occur sufficiently often to show on the chart at all.

Comment: Related if not duplicates: [“Five foot ten” or “five feet ten”?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/120013/) and [“6-foot tall” or “6-feet tall”?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/176582/6-foot-tall-or-6-feet-tall) and [X feet long/high versus (a/an) x-foot.](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/52346/x-feet-long-high-versus-a-an-x-foot-noun)

Answer (score 1):

As you said, you're not 'counting feet' - you are stating an overall measurement as an attribute of the snow.

When you are using any kind of measurement such as *feet, miles, gallons* etc as an adjective, you can use the singular form.

For example:

- I drove 6 **miles** (measurement)
- I had a 6-**mile** drive (adjective operating on 'drive')

So you could say "there **was** a 6-**foot** snowdrift".

However, keeping the structure of your example, you are talking about '6 feet **of** snow', so you should keep the plural 'feet'), but as "snow" is a non-count noun, you should not use 'were', as this refers to the snow, not the 'feet'.

So, it should be:

> There **was** 6 feet of snow.

Notice this [headline](https://nypost.com/2014/11/19/buffalo-chills-bring-massive-snowfall/) from the NY Post: **Buffalo is buried under 6 feet of snow**